# modelling multirotor aerodynamics using datalogs of flights

Tags: data-mining, data-stream-mining

I am trying to find a vector that would describe the effects of wind on a multirotor. I have a bunch of datalogs from a single frame of multirotor and am of the mind to digg.

The idea is that during flight a multirotor has 2 vectors to fight against:

- Gravity - to stay in the air and level height
- Wind

In a world without wind the multirotor would only fight against gravity when hovering and when flying in some direction. Each command the pilot makes is realized as gravity would dictate.

When we add wind, a certain deflection to multirotor angles occurs. If the wind is constant then the deflection is a function of desired movement and the wind parameters (strength and angle).

My idea is that across many flight logs the wind changes. You get average winds of different angles and different strengths. I would like to average out the wind effects and find a model that is the expected flight pattern when there is no wind. Using that model I would estimate the wind vector and using that knowledge I could do all sorts of clever stuff like choosing optimal flight speed.

So far I have worked on creating a database of data from the logs. Now I need to figure out how to proceed. How do I proceed?

I was thinking of trying to separate the positional (angles, height, speed, current consumption) data from the database and the desired parameters (direction, height, speed). Can this work as a sort of a set of labled data? The angle and current consumption show the effort needed to achieve the desired values. The multirotor algorithms try to be as close to the desired as possible and thus taking the angles and consuming as much current as is optimal in that point in time.

I would already be happy if I could label the wind strength into a few different levels to rough calculations for speed and other things. Levels like none, low, medium, high, toooo much to fly really.

Any pointers are welcome and since I am not well versed with this subject any keywords that I could read up on are much apreciated.

Comment: Might aswell simply look for a log that shows the least wind (angles are nearly 0 when standing still and not deflected when flying) and take that as the base for estimation. Take everything else as signs of wind. Find strongest effects of wind and take that as maximum and build up a continium in between, and try to classify rest of the flights on there.